# Change path to resource in Laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

Is there a way to change the resource path in Laravel Nova so instead of being `/nova/resources/articles/3` it could be `/nova/resources/articles/my-article-slug`?

I've tried defining `getRouteKeyName()` on the model, but it does not change the path in Nova. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name